# On Code::Blocks, I couldn't compile a source file. (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, avr, atmega, firmware

I'm a new learning how to code Firmware on Linux.
English is my second language so please excuse me if you are feeling like difficult to get what I'm saying.
Finding means about them, I've known the IDE called Code::Blocks.
So I'm trying to compile file by using it.

For the first time, I did it and the error says "Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))"

I guess it's the same situation with .elf file not found on Windows.
When I was on Windows 11, I used to set a path of make and compiler.

You know in the case of Windows, Users basically are used to set a ToolChain or a path as like "WinAVR20******\utils\bin\avr-gcc"
But in my case, I can't find compiler for avr and make file.

So I'm wondering where the files like gcc-avr and make are on Linux.

Like as I said, I tried find where the files are.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, on Linux you don't need to set paths as you are used to in Windows. That is, because after you install e.g. gcc-avr on Linux, any software can use that by simply calling `gcc-avr`.

In Linux, the main thing you need to do, is to make sure you install all dependencies correctly. A dependency is some software that the operation of your main software depends on.

In your case you want to use gcc-avr with Code::Blocks. Look in the repository of your distro for what you need to install:

- For [Manjaro](https://software.manjaro.org/package/avr-gcc)
- For [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gcc-avr)

You will see that for most distros, the package you need to install is `gcc-avr` which is an often used AVR development toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

> where the files like `gcc-avr` and make are on Linux.

**"gcc-avr" is not a file**, it's just a package name; the main executable of gcc for AVR is named `avr-gcc` (or `avr-g++` for C++).

To find their location you can

```
$ which avr-gcc
/usr/bin/avr-gcc-5.4.0
```

`which` only works when the `avr-gcc` you are searching for is in a directory that's contained in `PATH` (like `/usr/bin` usually).  You can very well place `avr-gcc` somewhere else, for example when you are building the tools on you own, you could place them using `--prefix=/home/me/gcc-13-avr` upon configure.

`which` will only find an `avr-gcc` there if, say, `/home/me/gcc-13-avr/bin` is in `PATH`.  If it is, you can for example.

```
$ which avr-gcc-13
/home/me/gcc-13-avr/bin/avr-gcc-13
```

---

> where the files like gcc-avr and `make` are on Linux.

Similarly, to find `make` you can run `which make`.  If it's not yet installed, then

`sudo apt-get install make`

or

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`